# "To make an impact in the community" or "on the community"?

Tags: prepositions

What is the correct preposition to be used with "to make an impact?"

> To make an impact **in** / **on** the community

Answer (score 1):

They are very similar phrases and can often be used interchangeably.  However, I believe the choice of adjective does add a small implication: it tends to indicate whether the person or thing making the impact is within the community or not, and whether its effect is visible from outside the community.

A person within a community will tend to perform actions which make an impact *in* their community, while a person or thing from outside (or an impersonal force such as nature or the economy) will tend to make an impact *on* a community.

There is also an implication that an impact *in* the community may only be noticed (or even visible) from within that same community, while an impact *on* a community is generally visible to the outside world.

Both of these are merely connotations granted to the phrases.

[Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=impact%20on%20the%20community%2Cimpact%20in%20the%20community&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cimpact%20on%20the%20community%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cimpact%20in%20the%20community%3B%2Cc0) shows that *on the community* is much more commonly used in writing, but scanning some of the corpus seems to indicate a preference for using "in" when describing actions by people or groups within the community being impacted (e.g. [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=Hp8q4z1OE8EC&pg=PA163&dq=%22impact%20in%20the%20community%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DIG_VMW1PIG6ggTc_YCYBQ&ved=0CDsQ6AEwBDgK#v=onepage&q=%22impact%20in%20the%20community%22&f=false) and [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=gDA_tQlmqtYC&pg=PA82&dq=%22impact%20in%20the%20community%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DIG_VMW1PIG6ggTc_YCYBQ&ved=0CFEQ6AEwCDgK#v=onepage&q=%22impact%20in%20the%20community%22&f=false)).

Answer (score 0):

Pons dictionary has "impact on sth" and OALD as well.

http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/impact_1

Answer (score 0):

You should go with **on** as it seems to speak externally.

"To make an impact **on** the community".

Comment: See, for comparison, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222694/contribution-correct-usage/222702#222702