# Impact [of something] on/in verb+ing

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage

The Guardian, a highly reputable newspaper, seems to use **"on/in"** interchangeable after **"impact"**.

Sentences 1 and 2 are mine, and I want to know if my reasoning for the usage of on/in after "impact" has any merit. I want to follow through on this "reasoning" consistently, and not write "on" one time and "in" another time. This is just for the use of **"impact"**, not in general.

Ngram shows "impact on reducing" is more often used than "impact in reducing".

> 1. The program's impact **on** reducing benefits . . .

Example: . . . family doctors can also have a dramatic impact **on** reducing emissions in the NHS . . . - The Guardian

> 2. The program's impact **in** reducing benefits . . .

Example: . . . such a scheme could also have an impact **in** reducing the climate footprint of the global plastics . . . - The Guardian

---

The following is my understanding/reasoning:

We say **impact on noun/noun phrase** - the impact [of something] **on the reduction** of carbon emission.

We say **impact in verb+ing** - the impact [of something] **in reducing** carbon emission.

---

Note: I have looked at questions from ELU and ELL on the usage of *"impact on/in"*. There is overwhelming preference for *"impact on"*. But in those questions/answers, *"impact on"* is followed by a noun/noun phrase. None of them specifically talks about the use of "in" when what follows *"impact in"* is a verb+ing. That is what I am asking about. Here are a few that I have gone through:

- [“To make an impact in the community” or “on the community”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47543/to-make-an-impact-in-the-community-or-on-the-community)
- [“Impact in” vs. “Impact on”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76986/impact-in-vs-impact-on)
- [Prepositions used with “impact”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49847/prepositions-used-with-impact)
- [Should the verb “impact” be always followed by “on”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/478204/should-the-verb-impact-be-always-followed-by-on)

Comment: You said _Ngram shows "impact on reducing" is more often used than "impact on reducing"._ One of them gotta be a typo.

Comment: Corrected, thanks Eddie Kal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this question has been sufficiently answered on ELU. As you've noted, there have been several similar questions over yonder and here on ELL too. That said I understand where your bewilderment comes from.

When you say someone/something has an impact on a thing, that thing is the object that the impact works on. In your example "*the impact on the reduction of carbon emission*", the noun phrase "the reduction of carbon emission", the object of the preposition **on**, is also the object of the impact at issue.

A footnote to this: the noun impact came from the verbal form, meaning "collide, strike against" (see its [etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/impact#etymonline_v_34564)), much as a strong force **on** an entity. It later evolved to include a figurative usage.

When you say something has an impact in a thing, that thing is a scope or context. This has been explained by several answers, and I won't go into much detail. Your suggestion is reasonable, but I wouldn't consider it absolute. The preposition **in** goes more with what comes after instead of before it. Think of "have an impact in reducing carbon emission" in this context:

> You were successful in getting the proposal submitted by the deadline.
>
> We did a lot of different things in getting him back on his feet.

Here *in NP/gerund* is the context/scope something happens. "such a scheme could also have an impact in reducing the climate footprint of the global plastics" means the impact is within the context of reducing the climate footprint of the global plastics. In other words, "such a scheme" (whatever it may be) could contribute to this goal: reducing the climate footprint of the global plastics.